# What should I serve when my webapp server has a bug?

Tags: java, http, tomcat

Basically I do not want to be penalized by search engine for "duplicate contents".  I'm concerned that, in some cases, the webapp server may be generating exception on pages that would otherwise display fine.

For example, users may post links to the following two pages on the Internet:

```
www.example.org/nice-article
```

and

```
www.example.org/even-nicer-article
```

Now my webapp typically shall return two different pages and they shall contain great content that is going to be indexed fine by Google etc.

My concern is that in some cases my webapp server may encounter an exception when trying to serve these pages: there may be a bug that we didn't caught on a previous release, the servlet may throw an exception because a resource it depends on is down, etc.

In that case, as far as I understand, there's some exception catching going on but I'm not sure what I'm doing is correct.

In my web.xml, I've got something like this:

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

and

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I'm not sure my web.xml is correct here.

My concern is that in the case of an exception getting caught, I display a message from *error.jsp* telling something like *"An internal error occured, please try again later"* but that for whatever reason I'd be sending this as a normal page and not as an error-page (and that hence all the broken page would get referenced as "duplicate contents" because they'd all be displaying more or less the same message).

Basically I'd like to know two things:

- what status code should I throw if a resource *that is normally available* is down when the crawling bots (and the clients' browsers) tries to access it (it's a 500 right?)
- how do I configure Tomcat to generate such a status code

Additionally it would be great if you could explain a way I could test this is working: for example can I *telnet* in and see if I get the correct error code?

Comment: I can't believe crawlers won't check the HTTP response code. They will definitely recognise 500, which is what every webserver returns for an uncaught exception (by default at least).

Comment: @biziclop: yup I know that... My concern is that I want to be sure I'm indeed serving a 500.  Somehow I fear that I could catch the exception and send regular pages that would all *write*, as content: *"Error 500: Internal server error etc."* but which would not be served with a 500/503.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use 503 error for temporary unavailable pages. This will tell any fair bot that the unavailability is temporary and they need to come back later to crawl the page.

Your error part of web.xml seems ok to me - how you checked that you're sending that message as a "normal page"? (which I think - correct me if I'm wrong - means you're getting HTTP 200 instead of HTTP 404)

Comment: +1... I realized that with telnet I can check all the status code.  I'm indeed getting the 500.  I'll see if I should change this to 503 or not.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181708&topic=1724951&ctx=topic

> Returning a code other than 404 or 410 for a non-existent page (or redirecting users to another page, such as the homepage, instead of returning a 404) can be problematic. Firstly, it tells search engines that there’s a real page at that URL. As a result, that URL may be crawled and its content indexed. Because of the time Googlebot spends on non-existent pages, your unique URLs may not be discovered as quickly or visited as frequently and your site’s crawl coverage may be impacted (also, you probably don’t want your site to rank well for the search query [File not found]).

I'm pretty sure the content of any error response code isn't going to be indexed, and therefore shouldn't penalize you for apparent duplicated content on generic error pages

Comment: And see this thread - http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/ESzKAjTq4Ec